# PHP getElementsByTagName('*') avoid duplicate nodes | "In Text ads" by separating content nodes

Tags: php, domdocument

the source of this problem is because I'm running ads on my website, my content is mainly HTML stored in a database, so I decided to place "In-Text Ads", ads that are not in a fixed zone.

My solution was to `explode` the content by paragraphs and place the text ad in the middle of the `p` tags, which worked pretty cool since I use CKEditor to generate the content, I thought images, blockquotes, and other tags would be nested inside `p` tags (fool me) I realize now that images and blockquotes disappeared from my posts, what did I do next? I changed my code to `explode` using `*` instead of exploding by `p` tag, I sang victory too soon, because now I get a lot of duplicate content, for example, if I have one image now I get the same image 4 times as well as all other tags, I´m not sure about the source of this duplicates but I think It has something to do with nested HTML, I looked for a solution for hours and now I'm here asking to see whether somebody can help me solve this headache

Here is my code:

```
    //In a helper file
    function splitByHTMLTagName(string $string, string $tagName = 'p')
    {
        $text = <<<TEXT
    $string
    TEXT;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $nodes = [];
        $dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $text);
        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName($tagName) as $node) {
            array_push($nodes, $dom->saveHTML($node));
        }
        libxml_clear_errors();
        return $nodes;
    }

    //In my view
    $text = nl2br($database['content']);
    $nodes = splitByHTMLTagName($text, '*');

    //Using var_dump($nodes); here shows the duplicates are here already. 
    $nodes_count = count($nodes);

    $show_ad_at = -1;
    $was_added = false;

    if($nodes_count % 2 == 0 ){
        $show_ad_at = $nodes_count /2;
    }else if ($nodes_count == 1 || $nodes_count < 3){
        $show_ad_at = -1; //add later
    }else if ($nodes_count > 3 && $nodes_count % 2 != 0){
        $show_ad_at = ceil($nodes_count/2);
    }

    for($i = 0; $i<count($nodes); $i++){

        if(!$was_added && $i == $show_ad_at){
            $was_added = true;
            ?>
            <div>
                <script></script><!--This script is provided to me, it adds the ad where it is placed, I don't show the full script, It has nothing to do with the duplicates problem-->
            </div>
            <?php
            }
        echo $nodes[$i]; //print the node that comes from $nodes array where the duplicates already exist
   }
   if(!$was_added){
       $was_added = true;
       ?>
       <div>
           <script></script><!--This script is provided to me, it adds the ad where it is placed, I don't show the full script, It has nothing to do with the duplicates problem-->
       </div>
       <?php
    }
```

What can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Postdata #1: I use codeigniter as PHP Framework

Postdata #2: My ads provider does not implement "In-Text ads" as a feature like google does.

Comment: You say the for each loop is not wrong. Fine, but you should post it anyway since it seems like the most important part of the code, since it's where you actually insert the ads

Comment: Just updated the code, foreach was replaced by a normal for loop to optimize code due to having to use the current position `$i` and having to have a counter variable

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are printing the "ads block" inside if statement. 
If I don't misunderstood your code is like

```
foreach ... {
if (strpos($html_line, "In-Text Ads") !== FALSE) {
print($ads_html);
}
```

I think, you should use str_replace() instead of print() like functions, if you are using something like print() when you outputting the value...